# jquery popbox not popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery

all!

I'm sure I'm asking a very basic question, but I spent a whole day on it, and just can't figure it out.

I have a table inside a tabbed box.  And to the table header row I need to add a button that will pop up a box for data entry.  Tabbed area works, the table displays, and the button also.  But when I click on that button, nothing happens.

I'm using the following tutorial as an example
http://gristmill.github.com/jquery-popbox/example.html

Added popbox.js and popbox.css to my html code and added

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $('.popbox').popbox();
        });
```

at the end of the html file.

However, it doesn't pop up.  I added alerts to the method, and popbox function does get called, but bind does not seem to get executed.  I added some alerts, but alerts are not triggered:

```
return this.each(function(){
    alert("test1");
  $(this).css({'width': $(settings['box']).width()}); // Width needs to be set otherwise popbox will not move when window resized.
    alert("test2");
  $(settings['open'], this).bind('click', methods.open);
    alert("test3");
  $(settings['open'], this).parent().find(settings['close']).bind('click', methods.close);
});
```

As far as I see, it's not popping up because the open and close clicks are not bound.  But not sure what is going on.  I'm a newbie at jsp and diving head in into jquery.  Apologize for newbie questions.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please share a JSFiddle example reproducing this problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/488Sa/1/    I simplified the code in JSFiddle, removing all other tabs and table data, leaving just one tab with the table header element in it. Also, in my "real" html, the tab references a jsp that fetches the data from the server. For this JSFiddle example I just entered the example popbox code directly into the div contentT element.

Comment: If I just copy the example alone, it works.  But when I enter the popbox code into the div contentT element (or via the called jsp), it stops popping up.  Something is overriding something, but I'm not sure what.  Thank you.

Comment: I deleted the script tags in the html tab and all the alerts are displayed and it kind of work

Comment: @IsaacZepeda, interesting.  It works, but then shows the script code below the button, which it shouldn't be doing.  If you remove the script tags it is not running the code.  My tabs aren't working then.

Comment: I think JSFiddle might be providing some hidden functionality, because if I remove those script tags my tabs aren't working, and the popbox isn't popping up anyway - it just displays the content inline.

Comment: If I change framework from "onLoad" to "onDomReady" it pops the popbox for a second and then closes it right away.  But with "onLoad" it never pops up.  I thought that I was using onDomReady anyway since in javascript I was calling $(document).ready(...

Comment: So JSFiddle example works if I move the <script> portion from html to javascript panel.  But what about my "real" code?  I have the initialization of jquery functions inside the script tags in the html page?  I don't get why it's not working inside the html page.

Comment: you are initializing the tabs in the HTML and the JS files, try to do it only in one of them